# Why does laravel event listener require wildcards?

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-5

This works:

```
     Event::listen('Illuminate\Console\Events\ArtisanStartin*', function ($event, $data = []) {
         echo "event: $event\n";
     });
```

But this produces an error:

```
     Event::listen('Illuminate\Console\Events\ArtisanStarting', function ($event, $data = []) {
         echo "event: $event\n";
     });
```

Why is that? The first one outputs `event: Illuminate\Console\Events\ArtisanStarting`, the second one produces the error message `Object of class Illuminate\Console\Events\ArtisanStarting could not be converted to string`. The should both work the same way. Why is the wildcard required? Am I registering the event listener incorrectly?

Comment: the error because of ur echo, try print_r($event); in ur second one.

Comment: @arunkumar Ah yes, that causes it to detect the event as an object instead of a string; silly of me to not notice. But, the question still is, why does the wildcard cause this change?

Answer (score 1):

From the [offical docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events#manually-registering-events):

> Wildcard listeners receive the event name as their first argument, and
>   the entire event data array as their second argument.

If you want an event name of a 'regular' event to be available in the listener, you have to pass it manually when you're dispatching it. In wildcard listeners the event name is passed on automatically.